# Nested ng-repeats not getting data from parent ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm pretty new to angular and I'm try to loop though a nested repeat. My html looks like:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning" ng-repeat = "producer in producers" >
        <div ng-init="beers=producer.beer"> {{  producer.producer }}</div>
        <div> {{beers}}</div> <!-- Returns proper json -->
            <div class="row row-same-hight">
                <div ng-repeat "beer in beers"> <!-- does not loop -->
                    <div class="col-sm-8" col-xs-height>
                        <div class="list-group">
                                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading beer-name"> {{ beer.product.name | uppercase }}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2" col-xs-height>
                        <div class="list-group">
                            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Six Pack: {{ beer.product.price | currency }}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

The section  "ng-repeat beer in beers" is not looping. However the variable beers contains the following json:

```
[{"plu":87692000495,"type_fk":403,"producer_fk":"Sam Adams","description":"No description avalible","single_fk":null,"product":{"plu":87692000495,"price":9.5,"name":" Double Agent IPL 6 Pk"}},{"plu":87692001058,"type_fk":403,"producer_fk":"Sam Adams","description":"No description avalible","single_fk":null,"product":{"plu":87692001058,"price":15.47,"name":" Boston Lager 12 Pk Can"}},{"plu":87692001270,"type_fk":403,"producer_fk":"Sam Adams","description":"No description avalible","single_fk":null,"product":{"plu":87692001270,"price":9.5,"name":" Rebel IPA 6 pk"}},{"plu":87692100126,"type_fk":403,"producer_fk":"Sam Adams","description":"No description avalible","single_fk":null,"product":{"plu":87692100126,"price":9.5,"name":" Boston Lager 6pk"}},{"plu":87692111023,"type_fk":403,"producer_fk":"Sam Adams","description":"No description avalible","single_fk":null,"product":{"plu":87692111023,"price":9.5,"name":" Light 6 pk"}},{"plu":87692271024,"type_fk":403,"producer_fk":"Sam Adams","description":"No description avalible","single_fk":null,"product":{"plu":87692271024,"price":9.5,"name":" Cherry Wheat 6 pk"}},{"plu":87692781028,"type_fk":403,"producer_fk":"Sam Adams","description":"No description avalible","single_fk":null,"product":{"plu":87692781028,"price":9.5,"name":" Blackberry Witbier 6 pk"}}]
```

Which looks good to me. I'm not sure why ng-repeat is not looping over that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ng-repeat "beer in beers"
```

should be

```
ng-repeat="beer in beers"
```

Comment: Thanks that was it. I've been glazing over that = sign for a while now :).